# Can't turn on location on android api23?

Tags: android, google-api, geolocation, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I have used the following code and the dialogue that asks for permission shows as expected. But when I click "allow" it doesn't do anything. The log message doesn't appear as if the permission wasn't granted so I went to my parameters to verify if location is "on" and it was "off". Wasn't it supposed to be on because I granted the app access to my location ?
If I manually turn it "on" and then run the app again, once it asks for my permission, it works and shows the log message but isn't the whole point of asking for permissions (via dialogue) to turn on location (when it's off) if the user clicks "allow" ? 
Am I doing something wrong ? I should mention that I'm running the app on api23

is is the code in my **Oncreate**:

```
 mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

 mApiClient.connect();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
```

and this is my **OnConnected** method:

```
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            //start the service
//checking and asking for permission

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                }
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mApiClient);

            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            } else {
                //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
                currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                Log.v("currentLatitude",currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "");
            }

    }
```

Comment: The app permission is completely different from the Location setting.  For prompting the user to enable Location mode, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31816683/4409409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
private LocationCoord gps = null;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

In OnCreate():

```
//GPS Manage
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        // notify user
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Allow ImHere to access this device's location?");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                //get gps
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    gps = new LocationCoord(this);
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // permission android 6.0
    if (!checkPermission()) {
        requestPermission();
    }

}


private boolean checkPermission(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return true;
    else return false;
}

private void requestPermission(){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

You will need this permissions on the Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

You can get LoocationCord.java here: https://github.com/toomyy94/ImHere-Chatbot/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pt/ua/tomasr/imhere/modules/LocationCoord.java

Answer (score 1):

you might have to add a dependency in your build.gradle:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1`